# Logistic regression with time-specific intercept

Tags: r, regression, logistic, python

I'm trying to fit a pooled logistic regression model with time-specific intercept on time-series data, i.e., $$\text{logit}   Pr(y|t,x)=\beta_0(t)+\beta_1x.$$

The pooled data set contains person-month samples, where I have multiple observations for each person at different times $t$.

What estimator should I use to estimate the coefficients? Is there any package in Python or R that I can use for fitting such a model?

Comment: I'd recommend the `mgcv` package in R, which allows you to create a spline for the time variable $t$ and does all the heavy lifting (generalized cross-validation etc.) for you.

Comment: I would guess you can turn the month into a factor, then just use it in `glm`.